# getNeighboringCellInfo returns an empty value in samsung

Tags: android

Neighboring cell info always returns an empty values in most of the devices. Also i have found  an article suggested to use the getCellAllInfo but that supports only for the API 17 and above. Kindly please suggest me the solution to get the cell tower info atleast 3.

Below is my code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager
                .getCellLocation();

    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
    String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
    String mnc = networkOperator.substring(3);
    int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
    int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
    int psc = cellLocation.getPsc();
    List<NeighboringCellInfo> NeighboringList = telephonyManager
     .getNeighboringCellInfo();
    int = NeighboringList.size()
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of the values I have received with the code I have posted]